# R - knitr::kable("html) - col.names from names(list)

Tags: r, knitr, blogdown, kable

I'm working on a blogdown post in RStudio. At one point, a chunks output is a named list with named number vectors, structured like this:

```
object <- list("Name One" = c("A" = 1, "B" = 1), "Name two" = c("C" = 2, "D" = 2))
```

What I want to do is to use:

```
object %>% 
    knitr::kable("html", col.names = X)
```

to render the output in a nice HTML table. The rendered `col.names` in this example should be `"Name One"` and `"Name Two"`.

Of course, something in the manners of `col.names = names(object)` would be perfect!

This is the **error message** I receive:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

I understand that each column header is being a rendered as:

```
<tr>
  <th style="text-align:left;">   </th>
  <th style="text-align:right;"> x </th>
</tr>
```

Notice the empty first cell.

Each named number column is being rendered as:

```
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:left;"> A </td>
  <td style="text-align:right;"> 1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:left;"> B </td>
  <td style="text-align:right;"> 1 </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried using a vector `c("Name One","name Two")`, a vector `c("Name One","n","Name Two","n")`, and various `seq()` and `rep()` combinations without success.

A more realistic example is here
Looking forward to any tidy hints.

Edit: I just added `object %>%` to make my goal more explicit. In order to reproduce this, you would need to run this chunk in R Markdown / Notebook:

```
object <- list("Name One" = c("A" = 1, "B" = 1), "Name two" = c("C" = 2, "D" = 2))
# cf. names(object)
object %>% 
    knitr::kable("html", col.names = names(object))
```

Comment: I don't quite get what the end output you want here is. Why not covert the list to a data.frame with the format that you want?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just updated my post and made my goal more explicit. The chunk below is reproducible in .Rmd

Answer (score 1):

So my guess is that you want a table like (if not do feel free to say so)

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> Name.one </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> Name.two </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> A </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> B </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For this if you have it in a `data.frame` (or `tibble`) format you can generate it via this:

```html
data.frame("Name one"=c("A","B"), "Name two"=c(1, 2)) %>% kable(format="html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Emi's solution above, and also here are two other options that render nicely on web pages including one from my favorite `DT` package (lots more options at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ -- there is a lot of whitespace on this one):

```
library(DT)
data.frame(as.vector(object)) %>% 
    datatable(options=list(dom='t'),colnames=names(object))
```

[image]

Here is another from `flextable`:

```
library(flextable)
data.frame(as.vector(object)) %>% 
    regulartable() %>% set_header_labels(names(object))
```

[image]